# Positioning of a View at runtime

Tags: android, view

i want to use a unknown (at begin) number of Views in my CustomView, so I have to set the position of each of them programatically. The problem is that I cannot use setX()/... or seTop()/... , because Im developing for froyo. But how can I set the position else?

Comment: If you're writing a custom view with children, you can write whatever functionality you want to lay them out.  I think that you meant to ask something else and your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: Do You really need absolute positioning? There is a lot of built-in layouts. Maybe one of them will suit your needs?

Comment: Well, I want to display some custom views in a list order without scrollbar, thus the "liscontainer" have to manage the size (with respect of "extra rules" in certain cases) of the custom views, too. Furthermore, I don't know the number of elements which have to be displayed. So I cannot use a simple LinearLayout. I think I have to implement this, right ?

Answer (score 0):

With `RelativeLayout` you can do the following:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();

layoutParams.leftMargin = x;
layoutParams.topMargin = y;

child.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```